# Rails and Sorcery gem and user permissions on content editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am experimenting with sorcery and rails 4 and I am struggling to understand what is the way to prevent users from editing or destroying content which does not belong to them. Say, I have a blog post and somewhere a panel which is like

```
<% if current_user? %>
  <ul>
    <li><%= link_to "edit", edit_post_path %></li>
    <li><%= link_to "destroy", @post, method: :delete %></li>
  </ul>
<% end %>
```

Of course users who are logged out can't see these controls, but whoever's logged in can delete or edit the post freely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorcery is for "authentication", but the problem you faced is "authorization". These two are different concepts.

"authentication" is to identify who this user is, but it can't make judgement what he can do.

"authorization" can do nothing without "authenticaton", but it's job is different. It can judge if this user can do something.

So your problem falls into the area of "authorization", this is not Sorcery's job.

Instead you can use CanCan or other gem for authority.

Sample code

```
def user
  # Can delete and edit his own post
  can :manage, Post, :user_id => user.id
end
```

You can check CanCan for details: https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

Comment: Thank you for this, I guess I will get my hands on CanCan

Comment: Yes, you definitely should :)